# Java Swing UI replacement

Tags: java, swing

I have to create a desktop application (.exe) where I can use Java swing. The backend code for performing some database operations are written in Java. It will be easy to write the UI in Swing but I want to know if there is something better available than Swing which will look much better than the Swing UI.

Can I use Flex? Can it be easily merged with Java code. Please suggest if any one know any other better options to develop this application.

Comment: Yes, Yyu can use Flex for sure. And you can get it work with Java pretty easily.

Comment: *"better available than Swing"*  a) Using what PLAF? b) 'better' in what ways specifically?

Comment: *"desktop application (.exe)"*  Better to install (and auto-update) the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It works for deploying apps. to Windows, OS X & *nix.

Comment: by "better" i meant good looking UI and which will be compatible with Java just as Swing is. Platform will be Windows. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I would say your best bet is JavaFX2 (this comes with the latest Java 7 releases). This offers a rich modern user interface, and you construct it in Java (optionally combined with XML). JavaFX2 is Oracles official replacement of AWT/Swing, which will not be developed any further.

This image (taken from Oracle documentation) provides some examples.

[image: JavaFX 2 examples]

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX 2 is the more modern replacement for Swing, which is currently relatively young but will likely gain much more momentum when Java 8 is released next year. (With JavaFX 2 the old FXScript has also gone, the API now is pure Java.) Personally speaking, I find the API much easier to learn and much nicer to work with, and aesthetically the default cross platform look actually looks good.

See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6):

> *Is JavaFX replacing Swing as the new client UI library for Java SE?*
>
> Yes. However, Swing will remain part of the Java SE specification for the foreseeable future, and therefore included in the JRE. While we recommend developers to leverage JavaFX APIs as much as possible when building new applications, it is possible to extend a Swing application with JavaFX, allowing for a smoother transition.

If you want something that keeps the native look (JavaFX doesn't provide a native skin that I know of at present) then you may want to look at SWT (Like AWT in that it uses native components, but it's much more modern) or qt-jambi (Java bindings for the native QT toolkit.) SWT is probably the more popular and supported of the two.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html. I would suggest you to use javafx. It is similar to swing. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/.